# Python-magic installation error - ImportError: failed to find libmagic

Tags: python-2.7, python-magic

I am trying to install python-magic for Windows and I have followed all the instructions in https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic and repeated the process several times but I am still getting this error:

```
ImportError: failed to find libmagic. Check your installation
```

I have magic1.dll (along with the two other files the docs specified) in C:\Windows\System32 so I am not sure what the issue is. I would appreciate any help or workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below original answer is now outdated. Please simply follow the instructions denoted under the "dependencies" section.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I was able to solve this problem by moving the 3 files from GNUWin32 project to a separate directory (not the \system32 directory the docs suggest) and adding them to the PATH environment variable

Comment: which files? where did you put them?

Comment: I think this answer is outdated now. There used to be 3 files you had to manually deal with. now you should just follow the directions under "Dependencies"

Answer (score 9):

Go [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic-bin/0.4.14) and download the file "python_magic_bin-0.4.14-py2.py3-none-win32.whl", then

```
pip install python_magic_bin-0.4.14-py2.py3-none-win32.whl
```

now `python-magic` works

[image]

Comment: THIS.  You don't need to install Cygwin, either.

Comment: the amd64 package on Win10 ... obviously ...

Comment: @user7660047, where is the problem?

Comment: Did not help in my case. It says "Requirement already satisfied" but still won't work. Note that I had to use the amd64 package on Win10, the win32 didn''t work at all.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a Windows question, but i wanted to share a **Debian** solution:

```
apt-get install libmagic-dev
```

Kind regards.

Comment: Why do you post a debian solution if this is windows question?

Comment: Because people who are looking for solutions on their Linux questions still find this page on web searches, like me.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps.

1. go to > https://github.com/pidydx/libmagicwin64
2. download the 3 files (dll's) except readme.md file
3. Drop the 3 files (dlls ) in C:\Windows\System32 and python magic will
   import correctly.

Comment: I am getting "ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation", using PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Cygwin with libmagic libary and installing the most recent version of the module from Github solves this problem.

At the time this question was asked, https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic probably didn't support cygmagic-1.dll.